# Fif Game in C++

Tags: c++

Fif Game: 9 squares labeled 1-9.  I'm taking turns against the computer to place an X or O on each of the 9 squares.  The first to get a sum of 15 with atleast 3 squares wins.

I'm trying to complete the C++ program of the Fif game.  I found some code online for tic-tac-toe.  I borrowed some of that, modified it a bit (but I'm not finished), and made it into the "Fif" game.  It works except for a few things.  The index is off by 1 (which is minor).  Also, more importantly, it needs 3 things.  1.Static Evaluation to judge the computer's moves.  2. Move Generator  3. Alpha-Beta Pruining.  I didn't fully use the template the teacher gave us for this assignment, but he did have a full alpha-beta function, which I think is the only thing I'm lacking since the program basically works.  I'll post the alpha-beta and then what I have.  Basically I need help putting everything together.

```
     float AlphaBeta(State S, Ply N, float Alpha, float Beta)
  //Recusively score state S using evaluation function Eval
  //and an N - Ply state space graph.
  {
    State Next;
    ListIndex I;
    float V, Value, BestScore;
    List L;                   //successors of S at this level

    if ((N == 0) || Terminal(S))
    {
      Value = Eval(S);
      T[S] = Value;    //record values only to confirm cut offs

    if (Value > 100)            //machine win
      return INT_MAX;
    else if (Value < -100)      //machine loss
      return  -INT_MAX;
    else if (Value == 0)        //draw
      return 0;
    else
      return Value;
    }
    else
    {
      if (MachineMove(N))         //program's move
    BestScore = Alpha;
      else
    BestScore = Beta;

      I = 1;
      while (I <= MaxNum)
      {
    Next = Child(S, I);
    V = AlphaBeta(Next, N - 1, Alpha, Beta);

    if (MachineMove(N))       //program's move
    {
      BestScore = Max(V, BestScore);
      Alpha = BestScore;
      if (Alpha >= Beta)
      {
        BestScore = Beta;
        I = MaxNum;           //prune remaining S successors
      }
    }
    else
    {
      BestScore = Min(V, BestScore);
      Beta = BestScore;
      if (Alpha >= Beta)
      {
        BestScore = Alpha;
        I = MaxNum;           //prune remaining S successors
      }
    }
    I = I + 1;
      }
      return BestScore;
    }
  }


//My Fif Program itself

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
//global constants
const char X = 'X';
const char O = 'O'; 
const char EMPTY = ' ';
const char TIE = 'T';
const char NO_ONE = 'N';
// function prototypes 

char askYesNo(string question);
int askNumber(string question, int high, int low = 1);
char humanPiece();
char opponent(char piece);
void displayBoard(const vector<char>& board);
char winner(const vector<char>& board);
int humanMove(const vector<char>& board, char human);
bool isLegal(const vector<char>& board, int move);
int humanMove(const vector<char>& board, char human);
int computerMove(vector<char> board, char computer);
void announceWinner(char winner, char computer, char human);
//main function
int main()
{

int move;
const int NUM_SQUARES = 9;
vector<char> board(NUM_SQUARES, EMPTY);
char human = humanPiece();
char computer = opponent(human);
char turn = X;
int ChoiceToPlayAgain;
string question;

cout << "Welcome to the 'Fif' Game!  You are competing aganst the computer."<<endl;  
cout << "Below is the board that you are using.  The object of the game is to" <<endl;
cout << "make your values to where you can get 3 of the values to sum to 15."<<endl;  
cout << "Valid input values are from 1-9" <<endl<<endl;

cout<<"123456789"<<endl;
displayBoard(board);
while (winner(board) == NO_ONE)
{
if (turn == human)
{
move = humanMove(board, human);
board[move] = human;
}
else
{
move = computerMove(board, computer);
board[move] = computer;
}
cout<<"123456789"<<endl;
displayBoard(board);
turn = opponent(turn);
}
announceWinner(winner(board), computer, human);
system("pause");
return 0;
}



char askYesNo(string question)
{
char response;
do
{
cout << question << "(C/Y): ";
cin >> response;
} while (response != 'y' && response != 'n');
return response;
}
int askNumber(string question, int high, int low)
{
int number;
do
{
cout << question << " (1-9): ";
cin >> number;
}while (number > high || number < low);
return number;
}
char humanPiece()

{
char go_first = askYesNo("Should I start or you?");
if (go_first == 'Y')
{
cout << "Make your move:";
return X;
}
else
{
cout << "I will start:";
return O;
}
}
char opponent(char piece)
{
if (piece == X)
return O;
else
return X;
}
void displayBoard(const vector<char>& board)
{
cout << board[0] << board[1] << board[2]<< board[3] << board[4] << board[5]<< board[6] << board[7] << board[8];

cout << "\n\n";
}
char winner(const vector<char>& board)
{
//all possible winning rows
const int WINNING_ROWS[8][3] = { 
{4,9,2},
{3,5,7},
{8,1,6},
{4,3,8},
{9,5,1},
{2,7,6},
{4,5,6},
{2,5,8}
 };
const int TOTAL_ROWS = 8;
//if any winning row has three value that are the same (and not EMPTY),
// then we have a winner
for(int row = 0; row < TOTAL_ROWS; ++row)
{
if ( (board[WINNING_ROWS[row][0]] != EMPTY) &&
(board[WINNING_ROWS[row][0]] == board[WINNING_ROWS[row][1]]) &&
(board[WINNING_ROWS[row][1]] == board[WINNING_ROWS[row][2]]) )
{
return board[WINNING_ROWS[row][0]];
}
}
//since nobody has won, check for a tie (no empty squares left)
if (count(board.begin(), board.end(), EMPTY) == 0)
return TIE;
// since nobody has won it isn't a tie, the game ain't over 
return NO_ONE;
}
bool isLegal(int move, const vector<char>& board)
{
return (board[move] == EMPTY);
}
int humanMove(const vector<char>& board, char human)
{
int move = askNumber("Where will you move?", (board.size()-1));
while (!isLegal(move, board))
{

cout << "\nThis square is already taken, choose a different square. \n";
move = askNumber("Where will you move?", (board.size()-1));
}
return move;
}
int computerMove(vector<char> board, char computer)
{
cout << "I'll take number: ";
//if computer can win on next move, make that move
for(int move = 1; move < board.size(); ++move)
{
if (isLegal(move, board))
{
board[move] = computer;
if (winner(board) == computer)
{
cout << move << endl;
return move;
}
//done checking this move, undo it
board[move] = EMPTY;
}
}
//if human can win on next move, block that move
char human = opponent(computer);
for(int move = 1; move < board.size(); ++move)
{
if (isLegal( move, board))
{
board[move] = human;
if (winner(board) == human)
{ 
cout << move << endl;
return move;

}
// done checking this move, undo it
board[move] = EMPTY;
}
}
// the best moves to make, in order
const int BEST_MOVES[] = {5,4,2,8,6,9,3,7,1};
// since no one can win on next move, pick best open square
for(int i = 1; i <board.size(); ++i)
{
int move = BEST_MOVES[i];
if (isLegal(move, board))
{
cout << move << endl;
return move;
}
}
}
void announceWinner(char winner, char computer, char human)
{

if (winner == computer)
{
cout << winner << "'s won!\n";
cout << "3 of my numbers sums to 15, so you lose! "<<endl;
}
else if (winner == human)
{
cout << winner << "'s won!\n";
cout << "3 of your numbers sums to 15, so you win!" <<endl;

}
else
{
cout << "Nobody reached a sum of 15 after board is filled, so it's a tie." << endl;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply the prof's alpha beta pruning to your program because your program lacks static evaluation.

You need a function that, given a board configuration, produces a value of how "good" that configuration is for the computer.

Your AI is in your computerMove() function and you laid out some clear rules:

1) If I can win in the next move, take it
2) If the human can win in one move, block it
3) Otherwise, take the next available "best" move

You have to translate these rules into numerical values. That function should return higher values for more desirable boards (for the computer).  So a board where the computer has won will have the highest value.  A board where he can win in one move will have slightly less.  A board where the human won will have a value of 0, etc.

Once you have that magic function, your computer needs to create all possible board configurations (potentially for multiple turns which creates a tree) and evaluate their "goodness".  The alpha-beta pruning will be applied to the created tree of board configs for pruning branches that no longer need to be evaluated b/c a better choice was already identified.

It looks like you still have a fair amount of work left if you want to apply minimax-ing and alpha-beta pruning.  Good luck!